# Monotone Functions

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem The function f is continuous on (0,1) , and takes every real value at most once. Use the intermediate Value Theorem to prove that f is strictly monotone on (0,1).

Comment: Please let us know what it is you are stuck on by showing us what you have tried.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if $f$ were *not* strictly monotone? What possibilities are there?

Comment: In using the intermediate value theorem I assume that there are TWO numbers k(1) and k(2) such that ,      f(0)<k(1)<f(1)   and f(0)<k(2)<f(1)

Comment: I am not even sure if I can assume this to begin with ...

Comment: If $f(0)<f(1)$, then there are certainly at least two numbers two numbers between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.  There are *infinitely* many, in fact. Before applying the intermediate value theorem, though, I'd focus on what it means that a function is *not* monotone.  I guess there's be an $x_1<x_2<x_3$ such that ... ?

Comment: Thanks mark for your response , A function not being monotone means it is constant??

Comment: Hmm... No.  A function is monotone increasing if $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ whenever $x_1<x_2$. A function is monotone decreasing if $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ whenever $x_1<x_2$. It's not monotone if *neither* of those happen for *all* possible choices of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. In that case, you must be able to find $x_1<x_2<x_3$ such that $f(x_2)>f(x_1)$ *and* $f(x_2)>f(x_3)$. (Or maybe the reverse as there might be more than one case to consider.)  *Now*, try to apply the IVT.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the Hint , I will try to comeup with a solution

Comment: Thanks again Mark for your hint : Here is my solution :Let k be any number such that f(x_1)<k<f(x_2) and f(x_3)<k<f(x_2) .By the IVT there exists a c an element of (x_1,x_2) such that f(c)=k , and also a c' an element of (x_2, x_3) such that  f(c')=k , but this is a contradiction since f thakes every real value at most once . Hence f is strictly mnotone....